# Android UDP broadcasting works but direct IP not working

Tags: c#, android, udp

I've published an Android app which communicates with a C# server app via UDP. I've implemented an "Auto Connect" feature which does broadcasting and receives an answer from the server. Once an answer received by phone, the phone app holds the sender IP and sends subsequent messages to this IP directly. Also there is a Manual Connect feature which sends data to the IP address the user enters (which is the local IP of the PC running the server app).

So, everything works great for lots of users but some users reported me that when they use manual connect, it never connects; when they use auto connect, the server gets the broadcast message (seems connected) and the phone receives the answer but afterwards none of the (direct) messages will be received by the server app. The common point of these users is that their PCs are connected to the WiFi router by wire and their phones are connected by wireless. I've tried the same thing on my network but again it works for me without any problem.

May it be because of having multiple network interfaces (both LAN and WLAN)? I've been searching net for 1 week but no success. 
What should I do? Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: well, i have an opposite problem: when PC is connected by wire to WIFI router - all works, but when I switch the PC connection to wifi (with WIFI router) - this PC stops receiving packets (they are not visible on wireshark anymore)